# How to test controller actions with complicated queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, controller, functional-testing

Supposing I have the following action:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.joins(:tags).where(:tags => {:id => params[:tag_id]})
end
```

It exposes `@posts` to the view, which will display every post with the given tag.

Everything works fine, but I'm stuck trying to figure out the best way to test it.

I don't really like mocking, since it could brake the test if I changed that line to:

```
@posts = Post.where(:tags => {:id => params[:tag_id]}).joins(:tags)
```

I don't really want to hit the database, as it'd reduce the test speed, but I'm considering extracting the query to a method inside the model, and test it there if it's the only way to do it.

**EDIT:** Yes, I know I could use `Tag.find(params[:tag_id])` in this case, but this is not what the question is about. I just didn't want to introduce another model in the query and make it harder to explain deviating the focus from the real problem, which is: Should we keep complex queries in the controller? If so, what's the best way to test it?

Comment: one collateral question, why not: @posts = Tag.find(params[:tag_id]).posts. It feels more natural, and little to test there.

Comment: Complicated queries should be scopes in your model, not in controller.

Comment: @tokland It's just an example of a query with `joins` and `where`, not a real code. I just tried to make it simple so it would be easy to explain what it does.

Comment: You should move all complex business logic out of the controller and into the model. So this question really becomes: how do I test this in the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, according to the comments extracting to the model is the best thing to do. That's how I did it:

post.rb:

```
class Post
  scope :tagged_as, lambda {|tag_id| where(:tag_id => tag_id)}
end
```

posts.yml:

```
one:
  title: Post 1
  tags: one, three

two:
  title: Post 2
  tags: two, three
```

post_test.rb:

```
test 'find by tag' do
  posts = Post.tagged_as(tags(:one))
  assert_includes posts, posts(:one)
  refute_includes posts, posts(:two)
end
```

Comment: Why on earth would you reinvent associations instead of doing `tag.posts`? Not to mention you ask for a tag id but provide a tag object.

Comment: You can do Tag.find(tag_id).posts.

Comment: @Rein See the answer I gave to tokland in the comments. This isn't the real code. I just tried to make an easy query so everyone would focus on the controller vs. complex queries testing problem. Unfortunately, I think the result was just the opposite, so I'm going to edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i like to do. Generally, i like to integrate database testing inside my tests( though some would disagree, i personally like it ). I would create like 3 factories(:post) and maybe some tags as dummy data and then i would call on the controller and check whether the received @posts is what i would expect.